# pyinstaller(telebot, telegram) An error occurs after 1 week

Tags: python, telegram

In `python3.9.5`, `PyQt5`, `Pyinstaller4.3 environment`

Telegram transmission error occurs after 1 week.
Exactly 1 week later, an error occurs unconditionally.
At least the number of transmissions within the program will cause an error.

It is the same even if you use two telegram modules.
Telegram transmission works fine until 1 week before.
Are there any restrictions on telegram api?

> python-telegram-bot
> bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_api, parse_mode=None)
> bot.send_message(channel_id, t)

**-> urllib3 HTTPError [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

> telebot
> bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_api)
> bot.sendMessage(chat_id=channel_id, text=t)

**-> 'OSError' object has no attribute 'result_json'**